# display fraction uitextfield

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitextfield

How can I display fractional numbers in an UITextField, e.g. 5 and 1/5 should be displayed as the number "5" followed by the numerator "1" on top, a horizontal line, and the denominator "5" at the bottom. Should I subclass should I subclass a UITextField?

Is there any sample code somewhere that shows how can I achieve this?

Comment: I don't have a detailed answer, but assuming you need to display non-trivial fractions not covered in the unicode set, you may need to look at Core Text or Text Kit. If you just need to display a fraction as a label you can probably just subclass UIView to make a custom fraction view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a commonly found fraction, you can find the unicode character (of 1/5 character) and then you can assign your textfield's text property something like this `"\u{2155}"` where 2155 is the unicode value of 1/5 character.

For finding out unicode values, you can use this website  http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/

For more reading on displaying unicode character, you may use [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html)

However, if the fraction is not a commonly found one, then for them there will be no Unicode characters. In such cases, you have to explicitly convert it into a string like `"\(myNumeratorIntegerVariable)/\(myDenominatorIntegerVariable)"`